# Conditional setup_requires dependencies in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Is there any way to tell **pip** to skip some *setup_requires* dependencies when not needed?

In my scenario, I have pytest-runner declared as a setup dependency (which is used to execute tests) in my setup.py. When I try to install my package (I.e: pip install my-package.tar.gz) it downloads pytest-runner or it fails it is not available (*).

In setup.py I have:

```
...
setup_requires=['pytest-runner', 'flake8']
...
```

I would like to tell setup.py only to use pytest-runner only when executing tests. Is that possible?

As @deceze suggested, this declaration will work:

```
setup_requires=['pytest-runner', 'flake8'] if 'test' in sys.argv else []
```

But I don't want to add logic to setup.py.

(*) The environment is very restricted, that's why downloading a dependency is a roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rwt](https://pypi.org/project/rwt/) (Run With This) seems to be the preferred way of doing this.

It provides on-demand dependency resolution, making packages available for the duration of an interpreter session.
One of its aimed scenarios is: *test runners*.

After installing rwt (*), you can load setup.py commands from pytest-runner module executing:

```
rwt pytest-runner -- setup.py test
```

or

```
python -m rwt pytest-runner -- setup.py test
```

(*) You still have to install an unrequired dependency (i.e: rwt), but it seems to have less impact than installing others.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to declare that as an [extra](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies):

```
setup(
    ...,
    extras_require=dict(
        tests=[
            'pytest-runner'
        ]
    )
)
```

You specifically install that with `pip install my-package[tests]`.

As an alternative: `setup.py` is a fully functional Python program… if you can detect your environment somehow, you can dynamically decide whether to add certain dependencies to the requires list or not.

Comment: Declaring them as *extra* wouldn't work because they won't be available when executing **python setup.py test** and I don't want to install them locally. Checking the environment is definitely an option, I hope not the only one.

Comment: pip install my-package[tests] is really cool! Thanks for suggesting